# How to simulate a CIR process using GPU and Matlab

Tags: monte-carlo, matlab, gpgpu

I am trying to simulate a CIR process using Matlab and my GPU for effeciency. At the moment i run into some implementation problems due to the recursive nature of the discretization.

The sheme I currently use is the simple Euler

$$V_t \approx \max \{V_{t-1} + \kappa_V(\bar{V}-V_{t-1})\Delta h + \sigma_V\sqrt{V_{t-1}}\sqrt{\Delta h}\mathcal{N}(0,1),0\}. $$

To proper simulate on the GPU I need some help function, like discribed in this [Matlab guide](http://de.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/examples/using-gpu-arrayfun-for-monte-carlo-simulations.html)

```
function [ V ] = simulation_fun( V, W, N, h, kappa_V, V_bar, sigma_V)        
t=1;
while t < N    % a path has N steps 
     V(:,t+1)=max(V(:,t)+kappa_V*(V_bar-V(:,t))*h + sigma_V*sqrt(V(:,t))*sqrt(h)*W(:,t),0);
     t=t+1;    
end     
end
```

Than I define the model parameters

```
N=1000; 
M=1000;  % Number of MC simulations
h=0.01;
kappa_V=1;
V_bar=1;
sigma_V=0.2;
V=gpuArray(ones(M,N));
W=gpuArray.randn(M,N);
```

After that I call the simulation via

```
V = arrayfun(@simulation_fun,V, W, N, h, kappa_V, V_bar, sigma_V);
```

and get the follwing error

```
Error using gpuArray/arrayfun
Indexing is not supported. error at line: 3  .
```

However, if I use

```
V = simulation_fun(V, W, N, h, kappa_V, V_bar, sigma_V);
```

it works, but the simulation is roughly 2.5 times slower than only using the CPU.

Does anyone know how to correctly implement the simulation?

Answer (score 2):

You should write some kernel functions in CUDA (Nvidia language) for your matlab code. Arrayfun is quite restrictive and not appropriate. 
Look at this link http://fr.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-gpu.html for more details about matlab and parallel computing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some restrictions to using arrayfun. 
[You can read the restrictions here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-element-wise-matlab-code-on-a-gpu.html#bsp51uy).

Judging from the error, you cannot use indexes the way you are.

You probably have to create separate GPU arrays for $ V_{t+1} $ and $V_t$.

I suggest that you find similar examples in Matlab's website and try to replicate its functionality. Here is an [article](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/gpu-programming-in-matlab.html) with information on how to program the second order wave equation on a GPU with Matlab.